# Не могу разобраться с циклом for

Tags: javascript

```
function double(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    
  // На вход функция должна принимать либо число, либо массив с числами.
    В первом случае функция должна возвращать удвоенный аргумент. (желательно циклом for)
    Во втором — массив, состоящий из удвоенных элементов входного массива.
    
  }
        
  return value * 2;
}
        
double(2); // 4
double([1, 2, 3]); // [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function double(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map(item => item * 2)
  }

  return value * 2;
}

function doubleWithFor(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    let result = []
    for (let i=0; i < value.length; i++) {
      result.push(value[i] * 2)
    }
    return result
  }

  return value * 2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function double(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    for(let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      console.log(+value[i] * 2)
    }
  } else {
    console.log(value * 2)
  }
  return value
}
    
console.log(double(2))
console.log(double([1, 2, 3]))
```